# Angularjs + Unable to call the directive code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Am new to angularJS, and am not able to make out why the directive is not getting called
I have separate js file controller for app, separate js file directive for app; Trying to create separate files for each;

[Plunker Link of the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jsb1eyvqiDT6IctPE9L8?p=preview)

HTML Code

```
<vertical-table data='fieldsList'></vertical-table>
```

Controller Code

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { $scope.fieldsList =[{},{},{}]; });
```

Directive Code

```
angular.module('plunker').directive('verticaltable', function () {
  console.log("field list initialzed");
    return{
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: 'table.html',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope : {
            data: "="
        },
        controller: function($scope, $elem){
          console.log("controller");

        },
        link:function($scope, elem){
          console.log("link");
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I'm experiencing same issue, can't wait for the answer...

Comment: try `.directive('verticalTable'` instead of `.directive('verticaltable',` (notice the capital T in Table)

Comment: Facing new issues :-) Error: Template must have exactly one root element. was: table.html

Comment: Use templateUrl instead of template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes to fix:

```
angular.module('plunker').directive('verticalTable', function () {
      console.log("field list initialzed");
        return{
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: 'table.html',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            scope : {
                data: "="
            },
            controller: function($scope){
              console.log("controller");

            },
            link:function(scope, elem){
              console.log("link");
            }
        };
    });
```

- Use `templateUrl` instead of `template`
- Replace `.directive('verticaltable'` with `.directive('verticalTable',` (notice the capital T in Table)
- Remove the `$elem` parameter in your directive's controller because you don't have a service named `$elem`.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/vyYl0KoDbbUIRs7IATE3?p=preview)